# What is the difference between tf and tf2?

Tags: ros, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What does tf2 add that tf doesn't have and why would I choose one over the other? It isn't clear to me what the difference is ... thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11242/what-is-the-difference-between-tf-and-tf2?/) by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2962 on 2011-09-18

Post score: 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

tf2 is a new implementation of tf with better abstraction and dependency isolation.  See the wiki page for an overview: [tf2](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf2)  The design of the new version is documented on the [tf2/Design](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf2/Design) page.

tf2 is still experimental and in the geometry_experimental stack and it is still recommended to use the tf package until tf2 is released in the geometry stack.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2013-11-01**:
This http://answers.ros.org/question/77061/tf2-migration-for-hydro/ and http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Migration#tf2.2BAC8-Migration.General_Backwards_compatability says tf is deprecated in hydro, "It is recommended for new work to use tf2 directly as it has a cleaner interface."